# I have two files that have the same character ('\n' or 10 in ASCII) but display differently. Why is this?

Tags: database, text, formatting, quickbooks, iif

They're both .iif files, except one is generated by QuickBooks and the other is generated by an application I wrote.  I've looked at the binary, and as far as I can tell there is no reason why they display differently in Notepad, and the one I wrote can't be imported into Quickbooks.

Edit:  I looked at the binary in Eclipse.  Windows requires an additional carriage return to display a new line correctly.

Comment: You've looked at the binary in...what?  *Notepad?*  Have you used a hex editor to show you the differences?

Comment: Check the file encoding?  In this situation I'd try and create the simplest QuickBooks file I could, and then try and recreate it using my application until I figured out what was different.

Comment: You do realize that .IIF files have been deprecated for like 10 years now, right? They can break all sorts of strange things when you import them into QuickBooks.

Comment: Native Windows command fc with the /b switch is appropriate. It will show you the binary differences. Or a hex editor.